# Angular - Array chamando apenas primeiro item

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lógica

Estou tentando fazer um calculo de um Array para exibir o valor total ao adicionar um item ao meu carrinho.

Meu array está assim: Utilizo o Status para informar na view que o item foi adicionado ao carrinho.

```
public pastelData = [{
  name: 'Pastel de Calabresa',
  price: 7.50,
  status: 'false', }]
```

Dessa forma ao clicar eu executo o service que altera o Status para adicionado ao carrinho e também captura o preço.

```
addItems(pastelData) {
    this.sharedSerivce.setItemData(pastelData);
    pastelData.status = 'Adicionado';
    this.getPricePastel(this.pastelData);
}
```

Eu criei a seguinte função para pegar os preços dos pasteis:

```
getPricePastel(pastelData) {
    for (const index in pastelData) {  
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < pastelData.length; i++) {
        console.log(pastelData[i].price);

        this.total += (pastelData[i].price);
        console.log(this.total);
        this.nextPastel.next(this.pastelData);
        return;
    }
}
```

Ela se comporta da seguinte forma:  SE eu deixo o return no final, ele pega em todas as chamadas de addItems apenas o primeiro preço. SE eu removo o return, todas as chamadas pegam o total dos price[]. E assim, não consigo chamar o preço equivalente ao item que o usuário adiciona ao carrinho

É um projeto para fins de estudos;

Comment: Ficou confusa sua pergunta, vc tem um array de objetos que possui uma propriedade com preços e quer saber o total dos preços é isso?

Comment: desculpe não ter sido muito claro.    Isso mesmo, porém, eu quero saber o total com base nos itens que eu chamei, e não o total de todos. 

Por exemplo: 

Meu array tem a seguinte composição:   [ A, preço:1  B, preço:2 C, preço:3] 

Eu não quero chamar todos ao mesmo tempo. Porém, da forma que fiz ele chama somente o primeiro. Eu não estou conseguindo acessar as outras posições dele. Pois criei um carrinho, dentro dele tenho a função "add itens" que chama meu produto, valor etc.. porém ao somar o total não estou conseguindo chama certinho

Comment: está te retornando o primeiro por que há um `return`  no `for`. Com isso a primeira interação é finalizada. entenda sobre [Laços e iterações](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sobre o tal problema em `for`, há [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) assim na primeira interação ao chegar nele é finalizado a execução desse método.

> sobre [Laços e iterações](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Pelo o que entendi, imagino que terá uma lista de pasteis `pastelDataList` no qual o usuário vai selecionando e assim o valor de cada vão sendo somados `total`. Bem, o código está confuso em entender para aprofundar melhor, porém vamos exatamente na dúvida sobre a variável `total`.

simplesmente você pode usar o [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), exemplo:

```
interface pastelData {
  name: string;
  price: number;
  status: string;
}

//nomenclatura mudaria para setPricePastel
getPricePastel(pastelDataList: pastelData[]) {
  this.total = 0; //zerar
  this.pastelData.forEach((data)=>{
     this.total += data.price;
  })
  this.nextPastel.next(this.pastelData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está parando o laço de repetição no primeiro índice já que tem um return isso para a execução do for.

Após remover o return calculará o valor total, poderia fazer o for assim:

```
let valorTotal: number = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < pastelData.length; i++) {
    console.log(pastelData[i].price);    
    valorTotal += (pastelData[i].price);
    this.nextPastel.next(this.pastelData);        
}
console.log(valorTotal)//Apenas para mostrar o valor a ser retornado
return valorTotal;
```